Spectrum of a periodic directed triangular lattice in the large $N$ limit
I am interested in whether there is a closed-form, or even approximate, result for the distribution of eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix of a periodic directed triangular lattice as the size of the lattice becomes infinite.
To be specific, I have been numerically investigating the lattice generated by the networkx package in Python (documentation link):
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import scipy as sp # need for nx

# 2d directed triangle grid graph
L = 64
Gtri = nx.triangular_lattice_graph(L, L, periodic=True, with_positions=False, create_using=nx.DiGraph)
wtriadj = nx.to_numpy_array(Gtri,nodelist=sorted(Gtri.nodes())) # create adjacency matrix for the lattice

This generates an adjacency matrix with $N = L^2/2$ nodes. According to the documentation, the horizontal directed edges point right and the diagonal edges point up. So, when looking at a single node, it has three edges entering at $\pi$, $-\pi/3$, and $-2\pi/3$ and three edges leaving at $0$, $\pi/3$, and $2\pi/3$, measured from the horizontal axis. Because the graph is directed, the adjacency matrix is not symmetric, and the eigenvalues will be complex. However, the matrix does appear to be normal. I attach a picture of the numerically evaluated spectrum and histogram for $L = 140$:


Some remarks:

Because each node has a fixed in-degree, the maximum eigenvalue is real and equal to $3$.
There are real eigenvalues at $-1$, with a multiplicity that appears to increase slowly with lattice size (e.g., there are 3 such eigenvalues when $L = 52$, but 5 when $L = 130$ or $140$.
There are additional purely real eigenvalues, but they do not appear to be consistent in number when increasing the lattice size, so I am guessing the limiting spectrum of the infinite lattice is purely complex, but this is one of the points I would like to understand.
The boundary of the distribution is matched well by a shifted cardiod $x(\theta) = 2(1-\cos \theta)\cos\theta - 1,~y(\theta) =  2(1-\cos \theta)\sin\theta$.
The density of complex eigenvalues inside the boundary is not uniform; it concentrates around the cusp at -1, and appears to increase near the boundary, as can be seen in the histogram.
Increasing $L$, it looks like the complex eigenvalues may eventually densely fill the cardioid; i.e., there is a limiting continuous density of eigenvalues as $L \rightarrow \infty$.

I tried searching for any resources that calculated the limiting distribution of this lattice as $L \rightarrow \infty$, but I was not successful, so hopefully someone here knows a reference or a straightforward way to calculate it. (There was a question about the finite periodic triangular lattice on math.stackexchange, but it went unanswered).
While ideally I would like a closed-form solution for the distribution of eigenvalues, I would be happy to know

is there a purely real part of the spectrum $\rho_{\rm real}(\lambda)$, and if so what is its behavior as $\lambda \lesssim 3^-$, and
the behavior of the complex spectrum $\rho_{\rm comp}({\rm Re}(\lambda),0)$ as ${\rm Re}(\lambda) \lesssim 3^-$. In both cases I expect $\rho \sim (3 - \lambda)^\alpha$ for some power $\alpha$ (that could be different for the real and complex spectra), and would like to know what the $\alpha$'s are.
(Less importantly) Do the eigenvalues at -1 form a delta function (atomic component of the distribution), or are they negligible and essentially become part of the bulk spectrum?

Thanks for any insight.

Parametrizing the lattice as $\{x+ye^{i\pi/3}:x,y\in \mathbb{Z}/(L\mathbb{Z})\}$, observe that for each $k,m\in \mathbb{Z}/(L\mathbb{Z})$, we have that $f(x,y):=e^{x \frac{2\pi i k}{L} }e^{y \frac{2\pi i m}{L} }$ is an eigenvector of the adjacency matrix with eigenvalue $e^{2\pi i\frac{k}{L}}+e^{2\pi i\frac{m}{L}}+e^{2\pi i\frac{m-k}{L}}.$ The map $(z,w)\mapsto z+w+z\bar{w}$ sends the two-dimensional torus $\{|z|=|w|=1\}$ onto the region enclosed by your cardioid. The limiting spectral measure is simply the push-forward of the Lebesgue measure on the torus.
The boundary cardioid is the image of the singular locus of the map, so the limiting density will have an integrable blow-up at a generic point on the cardioid (of order $1/\sqrt{d}$, where $d$ is the distance to the cardioid). The cusp is the image of the point $(-1,1)$ where both partial derivatives vanish, hence there will be a higher-order blow-up there, still integrable though.
